# Clearing console on Nuxt hot reload?

Tags: vue.js, browser, console, nuxt.js, hot-reload

In Vue I just edited the main.js file to add:

```js
// on hot-reload clear the console
window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
    if (e.data && typeof e.data === "string" && e.data.match(/webpackHotUpdate/)) {
        console.clear();
    }
});
```

But in Nuxt you only have the config file. I tried adding that script to the plugins folder but the console never cleared.

onReload.js in plugins folder. This file only seems to run when I refresh the page manually but not on hot reload (i.e. when I save any file):

```
console.log("hello there");
window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
  console.log("e.data is >  ", e.data);
  console.log("=== string > ", typeof e.data === "string");
  console.log("does it match > ", e.data.match(/webpackHotUpdate/));
  if (e.data && typeof e.data === "string" && e.data.match(/webpackHotUpdate/)) {
    console.log("hello world");
    console.clear();
  }
});
```

Nuxt config file:

```
  plugins: [{ mode: "client", src: "~/plugins/onReload" }],
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a plugin.

`/plugins/onReload.js` would contain your function:

```js
Object.keys(window.__whmEventSourceWrapper).forEach((key) => {
  window.__whmEventSourceWrapper[key].addMessageListener((e) => {
    if (e.data.match(/built/)) {
      console.clear()
    }
  })
})
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js` you would need to import the plugin, and disable server side rendering

```js
plugins: [
    { mode: client, src: '~/plugins/onReload' }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply above. That is exactly what i tried, and the console still shows the logs from the previous "session". I know the code you posted is working because I put a console log in the file before the window.addEventListener and I see it.

Comment: Please double check that you do not have preserve log enabled in your devtools https://imgur.com/a/UGD5D30, you can also run `console.clear()` directly in the console. Please let me know if it clears the log.

Comment: I can confirm that the "preserve log" is disabled/unticked. Running "console.clear()" directly in the console works fine. 
When i save a file and Nuxt hot-reloads, the console logs I have to test the onReload.js file are not appearing. It seems the onReload.js is only executing if I press browser refresh.. ?

Comment: After a bunch of hacking and inspecting. I found that `window.__whmEventSourceWrapper` is what webpack uses to produce the `[HMR]`  messages. I have updated my answer to reflect this. This has been tested and has proven to work in my case

Comment: Wow that's awesome, really nice find there! I didn't even think about that or come across it while looking around. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me so I ended up creating `clear-console.client.js` with the following...

```js
export default () => {
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept() // already had this init code

    module.hot.addStatusHandler((status) => {
      if (status === 'prepare') console.clear()
    })
  }
}
```

Then in `nuxt.config.js` add the follwing `plugins: ['~/plugins/clear-console.client.js']`

Hope this helps others.