# Nuxt - How can I remove the [HMR] logs from the console

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-hmr

With nuxt, every time I save any of my files, my console gets flooded with `[HMR]` messages. Often cluttering up most of the log levels, making it hard to see actual console output.

[One of few approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579348/clearing-console-on-nuxt-hot-reload) I have found is to clear the console. On reload. However, this approach does not fit my needs and seems excessive to stop these messages.

Another approach was to disable `autoConnect` however, this led to other issues.

Filtering out the messages in the browser, still let multiple `HMR` messages come through, and would not be persistent. Plus it has the added downside of cluttering up the filter.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to `nuxt.config.js` -> `build`

```js
hotMiddleware: {
  client: {
    noInfo: true,
  },
},
```

This should disable the messages from being printed to the browser console.

---

**Full Example**

```js
// Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
build: {    
  // Disable HMR messages
  hotMiddleware: {
    client: {
      noInfo: true,
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Could also filter it with the devtools no?

Comment: I use `gatsby` and get in the console `[HMR] connected`. How can I disable the message?